# Is it possible to extend a parametrized class to another parametrized class with one parameter inheriting from the first one?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, hashmap

I'm fairly new to Java so I don't know if this is a bad practice or even possible, but let's get to it.

I'm trying to understand the working of inheritance in a map. Let's say I have these three classes:

```
public abstract class Person{
    private String ssNumber;
    public void genericPersonMethod(){/*do thing*/}
}

public class Patient extends Person{
    private String patientID;
    public void specificPatientMethod(){/*do thing*/}
}

public class Medic extends Person{
    private String medicID;
    public void specificMedicMethod(){/*do thing*/}
}

}
```

And then I try to build some kind of crude database for each extended class. I've tried doing this:

```
public abstract class PersonDB extends HashMap<String, Person>{
    private RandomObject personDBGenericProperty;
    public void genericThingToDoWithAPersonDB(){}
}

public class PatientDB extends PersonDB{
    private RandomObject patientDBSpecificProperty;
    public void specificThingToDoWithaPatientDB(){}
}
```

But then I've found out it doesn't work and it can't extend `PersonDB` to another class effectively. If I just make some `PatientDB extends PersonDB` and `MedicDB extends PersonDB`, the problem is that I could theoretically insert both `Patient`s and `Medic`s, and I couldn't access either classes' specific methods because they're both considered `Person`s. Doing `PatientList<String, Patient> extends PersonDB` is even worse because it then accepts *any* kind of `Object`. I'm honestly lost about what to do next.

Also, even if this ends up being bad practice for whatever reason (in which case I'm willing to learn any available workaround), I'd still like to know if there's a way to do this in this specific manner, just out of curiosity.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the structure here. When you say that you can insert both `Patient` and `Medic`, is it via a method in the PersonList class? Also, while reading this data, you can type cast the `Person` to the required sub-class based on whether you are using `PatientList` or `MedicList`. Now one interesting bit here is how does `MedicList` know if it has received a `Medic` or a `Patient` from the `PersonList`. This can be handled by providing a discriminator in the Person class to tag a person as a medic or a patient. Let me know your thoughts on this!

Comment: When I say that I can insert both `Patient` and `Medic` it's because both `PatientList` and `MedicList` don't discriminate at all, since they both inherit from the `PersonList` class, which in turn extends from a `<String, Person>` map. Since both are `Person`s, I suppose they both fit into the list. I didn't consider casting as I understand it's less than desirable, so I'd like to avoid it if possible and have a strong discrimination. About that last bit, I don't really know how to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. May i ask why you think casting is less desirable. In any case, if you want a more strong discrimination, you'll need to maintain some sort of separation between the `Patient` and `Medic` instances. One way to do this is using the discriminator approach i mentioned. Simply speaking, you add a field to your Person class which tells you if a person is a `Medic` or a `Patient`. Now in your `PatientList` implementation, even though you are fetching the Persons from a common list, you can filter out the non-patients to ensure your `PatientList` returns only `Patients`

Comment: OT: Calling a (`Hash`)[`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) (`Person`|`Patient`)[`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is misleading, since these are two different, well-known containers in Java. I'd simply call it `Persons` or `Patients`.

Comment: Good call, they got that name because they were originally lists and then I changed types; I'll edit it right away.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would probably be to parameterize the class of person in the map:

```java
public abstract class PersonDB<P extends Person> extends HashMap<String, P> {
    private RandomObject personDBGenericProperty;
    public void genericThingToDoWithAPersonDB(){}
}

public class PatientDB extends PersonDB<Patient> {
    private RandomObject patientDBSpecificProperty;
    public void specificThingToDoWithAPatientDB(){}
}
```